# Legend in Google Chart not loading properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I am using Google Charts for displaying data and the graph loads properly, but the legend is not loading properly.

This is the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/7nvow4fw/) to my chart.

Please check the legend position and you will understand my error.

Below is my code,

**html**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#test">test</a></li>
   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#chart-test">chart</a></li>
</ul>
 <div class="tab-content">
   <div id="test" class="tab-pane fade in active">
     <p>
     this is the test tab
     </p>
   </div>
 <div id="chart-test" class="tab-pane fade">
   <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**my js**

```
graph();

function graph() {
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
        data = new Array(4);
        data[0] = new Array('a', 1, 3, 11, 15, 26, 37, 1, 3, 11, 15, 26, 37);
        data[1] = new Array('b', 6, 1, 7, 57, 26, 57, 6, 1, 7, 57, 26, 57);
        data[2] = new Array('c', 9, 2, 3, 13, 16, 17, 9, 2, 3, 13, 16, 17);
        data[3] = new Array('d', 4, 8, 2, 5, 6, 7, 4, 8, 2, 5, 6, 7);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() { drawChart(data) });
    }

    function drawChart(dataa) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Months');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Months');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Months');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Months');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Months');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Months');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Months');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Months');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Months');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Months');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Months');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Months');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Months');
        data.addRows(dataa);

        var options = {
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
                alignment: 'start',
                textStyle: { fontSize: 12 }
            },
            curveType: 'function',
            width: 900,
            height: 500
        };

      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
    }
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Checked your Code.
Everything is fine with your code. I think there is a CSS issue in it.
When I Just toggle a tab class in your HTML code it is working fine. replace your HTML.

```
 <div class="tab-content">
   <div id="test" class="tab-pane fade">
     <p>
      this is the test tab
     </p>
   </div>
   <div id="chart-test" class="tab-pane in active">
   <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the input..this works but the selection of the tab is not working properly. Alternate changing of tabs is not working as it should be.

Comment: sorry it works..i had to change the active class in li tag..thanks again !